# Create SharedPreference from xml

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am using SharedPreference to store data between activities (it's not anything settings-related, just user data).

I created these static methods in a `utils` class to handle writing to/reading from shared preference from anywhere in my app:

```
    public static <T>  void saveData(Context context, String key, T value, String typeOfValue) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("FILE", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        switch (typeOfValue) {
            case ("String"):
                editor.putString(key, (String) value);
                break;
            case ("int"):
                editor.putInt(key, (Integer) value);
                break;
            case ("Boolean"):
                editor.putBoolean(key, (Boolean) value);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        editor.commit();
    }

    public static <T> T loadData(Context context, String key)   {
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(FILE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            return  (T) sharedPreferences.getAll().get(key);
    }
```

I have these questions:

1. If I do this way, when is the preference file "FILE" created? Is it created when the application is installed or only when the first save or load method is called? Is it an xml?
2. What if I want to make sure

   - A shared preference file called "FILE" is created when the application is installed.
   - Inside that file, declare a list of permanent keys (no more keys will be added later) and have them all set to default values.

How do I do that? I heard that creating the shared preference from XML might help, but after reading the android api, it seems like this kind of shared preference is for the "settings" in android only.

I know that you can "kinda" set the default value like this

```
String username = prefs.getString("username_key", "DefaultUsername");
```

But I don't want this since all my read methods are generic. Also, I don't like this cause I don't really know what happens under the hood. It doesn't seem like the default value is actually set into the preference file, it might simply return the default value if a value has not yet been set.

Answer (score 0):

You can view the sharedPreference.xml.
Use Android Studio -> tools -> Android -> Android Device Monitor.
[image]

The file path is `/data/data/<package_name>/shared_prefs`
So you can test when the file created.

Comment: thanks, but I use genymotion and though I tried, I could never hook it with Android Device Manager, so I can't see what's actually in the Emulator...